# Output perl script on jsp page

Tags: java, perl, jsp, servlets

i am trying to print the output of perl script directly on jsp page.
i have been trying different versions of this lines on my jsp page:

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<c:import url="script.pl" />
```

i've put a script in a project directory
but keep getting this error:
 **Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
java.io.FileNotFoundException: directories.pl (No such file or directory)**

so where should i put my script and how do i print it's output to jsp page? 
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i finaly managed to do it in a different way. which is better for me cos id want to manipulate a data i receive and put it in a table on a page

```
    try {
        Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();                    
        Process p = r.exec("/actualdirforscript/scripts/ls.pl");
        BufferedReader in =
            new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
              out.print(inputLine);
        } 
        in.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
```